# Because Observable Subscription Happens on the Component, I'm Having Difficulty Refactoring Logic Into Service Layer on Angular 2 App

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

The one thing I'm finding in using observables in my Angular 2 app is that, because nothing actually "happens" until you subscribe to the observable in the component, that makes it a little tricky to refactor by moving logic into a service layer.

For instance, here is an example of a function that receives a sorting parameter, and then filters the data shown to the view accordingly. This uses an observable where subscription is happening in my components, like so:

```
onSortReceived(sort)
{
    if (sort === 'alphabetical')
    {
        this.filtersService.getByFilter(this.page, this.pagesize, this.body)
        .subscribe(resRecordsData => {
            this.records = resRecordsData;
            this.data = resRecordsData.data;
            this.data.sort((a, b) => a.name.last.localeCompare(b.name.last));
        },
        responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);
    }
    else if (sort === 'reverse alphabetical')
    {
        this.filtersService.getByFilter(this.page, this.pagesize, this.body)
        .subscribe(resRecordsData => {
            this.records = resRecordsData;
            this.data = resRecordsData.data;
            this.data.sort((a, b) => b.name.last.localeCompare(a.name.last));
        },
        responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);
    }
    else if (sort === 'id')
        {
        this.filtersService.getByFilter(this.page, this.pagesize, this.body)
        .subscribe(resRecordsData => {
            this.records = resRecordsData;
            this.data = resRecordsData.data;
            this.data.sort((a, b) => b._id.localeCompare(a._id));
        },
        responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);
    }
    else if (sort === 'reset') {
        this.filtersService.getByFilter(this.page, this.pagesize, this.body)
        .subscribe(resRecordsData => {
            this.records = resRecordsData;
            this.data = resRecordsData.data;
        },
        responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);
    }
}
```

Now, rather than have to repeat this code in each component that does this, I'd like to move much of this logic out to a service layer. But since the filtering is happening AFTER subscription, and subscription happens at the level of the component, I'm not sure how to do this. Is there a way I can filter first, and THEN subscribe to the observable? What would that look like? If I could do this I could move much of this code out to a service layer.

Comment: make use of the `filter` operator for observables

Comment: I would likely move all of this code into the services layer, understanding that this function would be subscribing to fetches that also exist in the services layer, and then you would call this function from your components, passing in the parameters as appropriate and getting back the returned final value. You could make this function return a promise, or even make this an Observable itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
filter: any;
onSortReceived(sort)
{
    if (sort === 'alphabetical')
    {
        this.filter = (a, b) => a.name.last.localeCompare(b.name.last);
    }
    else if (sort === 'reverse alphabetical')
    {
         this.filter = (a, b) => b.name.last.localeCompare(a.name.last);
    }
    else if (sort === 'id')
    {
         this.filter = (a, b) => b._id.localeCompare(a._id);
    }
    else if (sort === 'reset') 
    {
           this.filter = undefined;
    }

    this.filtersService.getByFilter(this.page, this.pagesize, this.body)
    .subscribe(resRecordsData => {
        this.records = resRecordsData;
        this.data = resRecordsData.data;
        this.data.sort(this.filter);
    },
    responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);
}
```

Then you could more readily move code into a service as needed.

NOTE: This code was not syntax checked or tested.

Comment: Thanks. The only thing that I needed to adjust with the above code is "filter" needs to be "this.filter" in the conditionals and, for the last conditional, it will error out on "filter = null", but "filter = undefined" works. One other note, with this kind of construction, it's actually the filtering part of the code (so, the first part) that I can then move into a service layer -- leaving just the last part to call in the component, where the subscription happens. And then it all works perfectly. :)

Comment: I adjusted my answer to match for anyone else reading this. Glad it worked out!

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account quote

> is there a way I can filter first, and THEN subscribe to the
>   observable

```
.map((response: Response) => response.json().data)
.filter(data => data.Type === 'myfilter')
```

or like this

```
.map(content => response.json().data)
.concatMap(arr => Observable.from(arr))
.filter(item => item.Type === 'myfilter')
.subscribe(val => console.log(val))
```